# Jenkins start is giving error

Tags: jenkins

when i am trying to start my newly installed jenkins by

```
sudo systemctl start jenkins.service
```

It's giving me this error :

```
[root@no52 ~]# sudo service jenkins start
Starting jenkins (via systemctl):  Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@no52 ~]# systemctl status jenkins.service
● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Automation Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-06-15 16:05:14 UTC; 25s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8226 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com jenkins[8226]: at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.current(JavaVMArguments.java:92)
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com jenkins[8226]: at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.daemonize(Daemon.java:106)
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com jenkins[8226]: at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.all(Daemon.java:88)
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com jenkins[8226]: ... 6 more
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com runuser[8227]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user jenkins
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com jenkins[8226]: [FAILED]
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com systemd[1]: jenkins.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Jenkins Automation Server.
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 16:05:14 no1010042210152.corp.adobe.com systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed
```

Can someone please help me with it ?

PS : I do have Java installed

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error usually shows, when you don't have Java on your machine. Jenkins relay on Java.

Follow these steps to fix the issue:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
systemctl enable jenkins
systemctl start jenkins
systemctl status jenkins
```

Hopefully it will help.

Comment: `:~$ systemctl start jenkins`
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See `"systemctl status jenkins.service"` and `"journalctl -xe"` for details.